# How can I know the compatibility between dimensions and metrics in YT analytics API?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api, youtube-analytics-api, youtube-analytics

It's hard to understand from the documentation as there are dimensions (to segment by) and metrics. But it doesn't show the compatibility between them.But I texted using the "YT Analytics API explorer" which gives an error:

How can I know which dimensions are compatible with which metrics in YT analytics API?

I'm calling the YT analytics API to get retention data. How can I know from the documentation which dimensions are compatible to segmentation?

[image]